# Python code for finding the largest prime factor is too slow. What is the error?

Tags: python, math

Trying to solve the problem: "Find the largest prime factor of 600851475143"

I'm trying to solve Project Euler's third problem. Since I'm just beginning, my codes are still quite bad, and I don't know many things about the language. I'd strongly appreciate some review. Thanks!

```
num = 600851475143
ans3 = []

primes = [x for x in range(num) if x % 2 != 0 and
                                x % 3 != 0 and
                                x % 4 != 0 and
                                x % 5 != 0 and
                                x % 6 != 0 and
                                x % 7 != 0 and
                                x % 8 != 0 and
                                x % 9 != 0 and
                                x % 11 != 0 and
                                x % 13 != 0 and
                                x % 17 != 0 and
                                x % 19 != 0 and
                                x % 23 != 0 and
                                x % 29 != 0 and
                                x % 31 != 0]
primes.insert(1, 2)
primes.insert(2, 3)
primes.insert(3, 5)
primes.insert(4, 7)
primes.insert(5, 11)
primes.insert(6, 13)
primes.insert(7, 17)
primes.insert(8, 19)
primes.insert(9, 23)
primes.insert(10, 29)
primes.insert(11, 31)
primes.pop(0)

for x in primes:
if num % x == 0:
    ans3.append(x)

print(ans3)
```

I don't know the answer, but it works well with smaller numbers (like the example, 13195, which outputs 29).

Comment: probably start by refactoring the one line alone to create the list: `primes = ...` with multiple `and` conditionals is not only unconventional but it takes about 30 seconds to complete just that one line on my machine

Comment: Furthermore, there are lots of unnecessary tests (how could a number be a multiple of 6 if it is neither a multiple of 2 nor 3?) and you list will contain lots of composite numbers (37*37 will be in your list of primes, for example). You should look for another way to generate primes.

Comment: As the other comments show, you need to change your entire approach. My solution does not even look for primes. I start looking at `2` on up, and if a number divides into the target I just divide out that number. I keep going until the target was reduced to `1`--then the last factor I found was the largest prime factor. My code is very simple and takes just six lines, plus one more to print the answer. However, you really should not ask help for ProjectEuler problems--that goes against the spirit of the site.

Comment: I see. Thank you all for your comments. I know the code is extremely inefficient. Since I literally started about two weeks ago, I think I don't have the needed skills for this yet. That's why I wanted to know about other comments and approaches, even if it goes against the project's spirit. Let's say it's a way of learning that's really efficient for me. Besides, there are lost of problems there, so I hope to solve them on my own at least from No. 10. Again, thanks. You really helped me a lot.